# How do I run a script when an api endpoint is hit?

Tags: python, flask, uri

Here is how I want my program to work. Step 2 is what I am unsure of how to implement.

1. Client makes API call to /email endpoint
2. /email endpoint has a script run that gather emails from GMAIL API
3. Put contents into response object
4. Returns response object back to client

I understand how to make a static api response. But I can't get a python script to run when the api endpoint is hit.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw the `flask` tag in your post.

I only played around with `flask` for certain interviews, but know enough to say calling a python script outside your running server is somewhat of an antipattern.

I assume your backend is a flask app, so ideally, you'd want to wrap whatever script you have in your python script file in a function and simply call it from your flask method when the endpoint is hit.

Something like:

```
from flask import Flask
from custom_emails_module import gather_email

@api.route('/email', methods=["GET"])
def method_associated_with_your_endpoint():
    # additional
    gather_email()
```

where `custom_emails_module` should be the module you create for your gather_emails script.

Now, at the end of your `gather_emails` function, simple remember to return the correct type, usually done with:

```
return json.dumps("success": True, "data": python_object_with_several_emails)
```

Use something like PostMan for local debugging and remember to use `application/json` in header for Content-Type.

Good luck!